# Java Bulk Email Exception Handling

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am attempting to send bulk email without create new session for every mail recipient because of performance considering.

But i am facing one problem in this. if one of the recipient is invalid, then job could not send mail to other recipients.
In this scenario i need to send mail to other recipients

Below is my code snippet, Kindly provide any suggestion for this problem.

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
message.setSubject(subject);

message.setContent(messageStr, "text/html");

if (mailTo != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mailTo.length; i++) {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailTo[i]));
    }
}

Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: validate the email addresses?

Comment: In worst case scenario, if any of the recipient is failed. then job is not sending mail to anyone.

Comment: so why don't you validate the email addresses?

Comment: Validation is OK.. i am thinking some other cases if failed.

Comment: *i am thinking some other cases if failed* - for example?

Comment: for example, i am parsing subject and body for every recipient with place holders before send. so if text is not compatible when send emails. like this some other problem[MessagingException] will occur in production, just i am assuming.

Comment: @Scary Wombat, Anyway Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Siva use thread for that create separate thread for each time you while you sending mail and use try catch that it.

Comment: Thanks and Noted @DivyeshKanzariya

Answer (score 1):

Set the Session property [`mail.smtp.sendpartial`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.sendpartial) to `true`.